# Dynamics CRM 2013: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I created a quite simple plugin for Dynamics CRM 2013 that should populate some attributes based on some other attribute values.

The following error message occurs when query data:

```
Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): 
Foobar.IsoCountry.Plugins.PreAddressCreateUpdate: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance 
security rules violated while overriding member: 
   'Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceRegistrationFailedException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime
.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. 
Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of 
the method being overriden.
```

The code is quite simple:

```
 var context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
 var orgServiceSystem = localContext.OrganizationServiceAsSystem;
 var target = this.GetTargetEntity(context).ToEntity<Account>();


 using (var xrm = new XrmContext(localContext.OrganizationServiceAsCallingUser))
 { 
     var list = from account in xrm.AccountSet where account.Name.StartsWith("foobar")select account;

            ///...
 }
```

I am using the lasts SDK Version (6.1.1) and targeting Dynamics CRM Online (Spring Wave Update is installed).

The only think that might be a bit special, is the fact that I am usiong ILMerge to combine multiple dll into my plugin.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I used an dedicated Visual Studio project for the data-access (repository pattern) and part of this project was a class (BaseXrmFactory) that used the "DeviceIdManager" class("DeviceIdManager.cs"; part of the SDK).

The class was used to created new instances of the org-service:

```
...
private ClientCredentials GetDeviceCredentials()
{
    return Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice();
}
...
```

Via ILMerge was this project include in my plugin-dll that was deployed to the CRM. Once I removed the class (DeviceIdManager) the plugin executed as expected :)

I do not fully understand way this was the problem because the BaseXrmFactory was NOT invoked as part of the plugin execution.

Answer (score 0):

I had two plugins first with Isolation mode Sandbox and second with isolation mode None. I set all isolation mode to none and after all working correctly.